# Как сложить запрос из апи чтобы получился такой массив

Tags: python

Апи ссылка

```
url='https://fapi.iisis.ru/fapi/v2/analogList?n=' + query + '&art={{art}}&brend={{brend}}&ui=')
```

запрос получает список ответов

```
{"manufacturerList":{"mf":[{"i":0,"ds":"SCHLIECKMANN","da":"SCHLIECKMANN","dbi":12533},{"i":5,"ds":"OM","da":"OM","dbi":13756}]},"productList":{"p":[{"i":0,"mfi":0,"ns":"213131","n":"213131","d":"","sr":0,"dbi":34910821,"upd":0},{"i":242778892,"pri":91,"si":8,"di":206,"_int":-1,"rm":0,"rp":1,"pi":3,"mfi":3,"ns":"213131","pai":5,"mfai":5,"nsa":"3910072j20"}]},"messageList":{"m":[]}}
```

- `part_nsa = [page['nsa'] for page in response2.json()["analogList"]['a']]` - артикул
  где mfai внешний ключ на бренды, его в одном массиве можно получить так
- `response2.json()["manufacturerList"]['mf'][person['mfai']]['ds']` - Бренд

Надо получить такой результат одним запросом:

```
results = [
 ['dx30706w', 'DEXTRIM'],
 ['cmz11414', 'AMD'],
 ['201295756','MANN'],
 ['ph2846b', 'FORTECH']
]
```

Буду очень признателен, cпасибо!
Решение: изначально неправильно начал) Всем спасибо) Если что вдруг кому то понадобится функция получения по апи

```
               class API:
                    def cross(art, brend, ui):
                        response2 = requests.get(
                            url='http://fapi.iisis.ru/fapi/v2/analogList?n=' + query + '&art={{art}}&brend={{brend}}&ui='+ ui +'')
                        return response2.json()
```

Comment: Приведите вопрос в порядок, сейчас не очень понятно, что откуда берётся вообще.

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Делаете один запрос, response.json() сохраните в переменную, потом из нее получайте данные. Но вообще как-то не очевидно, что данные по ключу "analogList" и "manufacturerList" должны соответствовать друг другу. В приведенном примере ответа вообще нет таких ключей.

Comment: @insolor Да вот именно, что пока вопрос не консистентный какой-то и мы можем только гадать о структуре данных.

Comment: Подправил полный ответ ответ от запроса от апи

Comment: Но ведь там всё-равно нет тех строк, которые у вас в `results` написаны. Пример должен быть реальным. На входе то-то, на выходе то-то.

Comment: сорян, не тот запрос выложил, вот сейчас верный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def cross(art, brend, ui):
    response2 = requests.get(
        url='http://fapi.iisis.ru/fapi/v2/analogList?n=' + query + '&art={{art}}&brend={{brend}}&ui='
            + ui +'')
    return response2.json()
```

Заново вывел результат запроса апи через функцию и отправил в цикл запроcа, вроде теперь быстрее отрабатывает (40.71ms) самый большой запрос.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]